# Window is not defined while importing an npm package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to learn how to create and publish an npm package.

I have created an npm package, https://github.com/nitte93/OnBoarding
for my learning purpose.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/onBoarding

It works fine in dev build, but when I try to import it in my isomorphic react app, I get : `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

I have not made any explicit use of the window object in the package, but there are places where I have explicitly use jquery.

Now, I am not sure but all I understood was, that while importing this npm package in my isomorphic app, I'm trying to use the window object in NODE environment, which I assume is wrong since window object is only accessible on the browser side.

My question is how do I handle this.

1) Do I need to handle this in my npm package itself.

2)Should I handle it in my Isomorphic app? How?

Please answer or point to a right resource to solve this issue.

Comment: You shouldn't use jquery, it is for browser only

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your repository, and the only thing I think could be the culprit is that the `semantic-ui` vendor js files are required in the `OnBoarding.js` component, which I assume is also a server rendered file. You need to instead require those packages that only run on the browser inside the client file (the one that will call `ReactDom.render()`.. I think it's `/src/example/index.js`).

Also, as a rule of thumb don't put any browser specific code in `componentWillMount`, as that does get called on the server. `componentDidMount` is safe, though, as it's only called in the browser.